# Dynamic Formula to give result Cardinal numbers

Tags: google-sheets, dynamic, google-sheets-formula, formula

I have been trying to count Dynamically the number of rows based on Col"B" as available in attached sheet.

Dynamic formula will give Countdown from 1 to onward based on col"B" values, such as

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

and so on

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did this do the trick:

```
=SEQUENCE(COUNTA(B1:B))
```

Answer (score 1):

or the logic way:

```
=INDEX(IF(B1:B="";;ROW(B1:B)))
```

or from row 2:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;ROW(B2:B)-1))
```

or like:

```
=INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("B1:B"&COUNTA(B1:B))))
```